# SQL String Comparision Ignoring White Space

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've one string like **'Supervision Charges'** in one table and in another table string is like **'Super Vision Charges'**, both string are same but one has extra white space,
how can i get the row of second table by using the string of first table,

i think if we **ignore** the **white space** in **SQL query** then it can be done, but, i don't know such type of query.

Comment: compare both strings as stripped spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
WHERE REPLACE (column, ' ', '') LIKE 'SupervisionCharges'
```